# ASP.NET TreeView nodes not expanding and collapsing

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have a TreeView menu populated from a SiteMapDataSource.  The TreeView defaults to all nodes expanded, but the normal client side expand/collapse behaviour for the nodes is not working.  I get one Javascript error in my Firebug console, being:

> TreeView_ToggleNode is not defined

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TreeView menu is on a page that displayed content pages in an IFrame.  The TreeView is bound to a SiteMapDataSource, and for convenience, the developer added a `<base>` tag to the page, declaring the target of all links on the page to be the IFrame.  The TreeView uses javascript links for it's navigation buttons and setting a base target breaks these all.

I solved the problem by selectively setting only the actualy menu links, not the expand and collapse buttons, to have a target of the IFrame, with the following jQuery:

```
$("#navigation a[class^=menu]").attr("target", "iframe1");
```